# How can I use subqueries in Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb

I would like to use this query in Memgraph, but it doesn't work (this is only part of the query):

```
UNWIND $data as rowData
MERGE (element:Element {item_id: rowData.item_id, revision: rowData.revision, identifier: rowData.element_id})
WITH element, rowData
CALL {
    WITH element, rowData
    WITH rowData WHERE rowData.has_superior=True AND rowData.superior <> ''
    MATCH (elem:Element {item_id: rowData.item_id, revision: rowData.revision, identifier: rowData.element_id})
    SET elem.sub_index = rowData.sub_index
}
WITH element, rowData
CALL {
    WITH element, rowData
    WITH rowData WHERE rowData.has_superior=True AND rowData.superior = ''
    MATCH (elem:Element {item_id: rowData.item_id, revision: rowData.revision, identifier: rowData.element_id})
    REMOVE elem.sub_index
}
```

Does Memgraph support subqueries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memgraph doesn't support subqueries yet, but there is [ticket for this feature](https://github.com/memgraph/memgraph/issues/784).